# How to set a threshold when coloring and labeling scatterplot points in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I saw a python graph that looks like the following:

[image]

I think doing something like this really puts emphasis on certain data points and takes away a lot of clutter. Using the adjust text library, I know how to label points with the following code:

```
from adjustText import adjust_text

texts = [plt.text(x0,y0,name,ha='right',va='bottom') for x0,y0,name in zip(
    df.x, df1.y, df1.label)] 

adjust_text(texts)
```

What could I add to this code to only label points that are, say, greater than 5?

Also, how could I go about coloring all data points outside of that threshold  (less than 5) gray, as seen in the picture?

I've been reading documentation to no avail, so I decided to ask you all here. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am using a dictionary to color the points, so I'm good there. I just would like to know how to convert data points that don't meet a requirement back to gray

Here's my code for coloring the points:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  ax.scatter(df.x.iloc[i], df.y.iloc[i],alpha=.7,color=COLORS[df.color.iloc[i]])
```

Comment: What does your dataframe look like? Also, what exactly is being used as your threshold? I'm a little confused by your dictionary `COLORS` as well.

Comment: columns are an x value, a y value, name, and a label. I want the threshold to be y>5. ```COLORS``` is a dictionary with hex codes for all names in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Calling `scatter` for each point isn't the most efficient. You can call `scatter` twice: once for data below and once for above the threshold:

```
threshold = 5
ix = df.y < threshold
ax.scatter(df.x[ix], df.y[ix], c='gray')
ax.scatter(df.x[~ix], df.y[~ix], c=COLORS[df.color[~ix]]
```

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

colors = list('rgbcmyk')
color_cycle = cycle(colors)

np.random.seed(42)
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((n, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
df['colors'] = [c for c, _ in zip(color_cycle, range(n))]
ix = df.y < 0.75

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df.x[ix], df.y[ix], c='gray')
ax.scatter(df.x[~ix], df.y[~ix], c=df.colors[~ix])
```

[image]